# Centering css dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a little problem with centering my dropdown menu. I've tried everything said on Google and this forum, but nothing helps and therefore i hope that some of you guys will help me!

My page can be seen here [testpage](http://simonhollander.dk/v/cash.shtml). Here you can see how misplaced my dropdown menu are. I wan't it to be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by:

- Removing `float: left` from `li` elements.
- Adding `display: inline-block` to `li` elements.
- Adding `text-align: center` to `ul` element.